# What kind of Fender Strat is this

Tags: stratocaster, solid-body-electric-guitars

I was offered a Fender Strat Custom Shop Guitar and I am interested in buying it but I have no info about it, only some pictures and would like to know if it's worth it. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[image: guitar]
[image: headstock]
[image: body]

Comment: Perhaps you can locate the serial number and use Fender's website to see more information about the instrument?

Comment: it doesn't have the serial number anymore. Thanks

Comment: The seller also has no info about it? Custom Shop Strats are not cheap. It would be strange for the current owner not to know anything about it, unless they did not acquire it legitimately. I haven't been able to find a Strat that has that art on it, so the art might be after market.

Comment: I would ask the seller for a photo of the neck plate (the square metal plate on the back of the guitar where the neck joins the body).

Comment: Looks a bit suspect to me, the logo on the front of the headstock doesn’t look right.

Comment: I've not see that chevron mark on the back on a Fender before.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis All you would need to do to change that is look at the photos of current fender custom shop models on the fender or reputable reseller web site. They don’t seem to be putting them in the middle of the back of the headstock right now, just found a picture showing it inside the scroll bit at the tip of the headstock, but its position has varied over the years.

Answer (score 5):

Normally, the Fender logo aligns with the bottom straight edge of the headstock. The logo is usually either golden and smaller or large and black. Smaller and black is not one I've seen.

I think the one thing I can say is that this guitar has never been in the Fender Custom Shop.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I am not buying it.

Answer (score 4):

A genuine Fender Custom Shop guitar comes with a Certificate Of Authenticity, which contains the serial number and describes the instrument and when it was made and sometimes also by whom. Without this document, the guitar isn't worth half as much. I'd be wary of a seller who claims to have mislaid this document.

If you can try the guitar, and it feels and sounds great, then go ahead and buy it for the price of a regular second-hand Fender. But don't pay a premium if the seller can't prove it's a genuine Custom Shop instrument and you have no way of verifying that claim.

Maybe only the neck is from a custom shop guitar. Maybe the seller just printed the custom shop logo on it himself, or the previous owner did and duped the current owner. Maybe it's a partscaster made with Mexican and Squier parts. There's no way of knowing, unless you can take someone with you who has experience in authenticating Vintage or Custom Shop guitars. Maybe you can ask in a local guitar shop if they want to accompany you when you go check out the guitar, in exchange for a fee?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'm not buying it. It's probably fake.

Answer (score 1):

A single detail -- the machine heads (first photo) aligned very, very poorly -- is enough to tell you this is no custom shop but a cheap copy.